# Use ALGO_ID_C14N11_OMIT_COMMENTS in xades4j

Tags: canonicalization, xmlsec, xades4j

I need to sign my documents using ALGO_ID_C14N11_OMIT_COMMENTS and ALGO_ID_C14N11_WITH_COMMENTS canonicalization. Can you tell me what should I change to xades4j to permit this (Isimply need xades_bes and xades_t, no verification by now).

Should I create a wrapper class in xades4j.algorithms like the already present? and then?

Answer (score 3):

You can create the derived class or use the [GenericAlgorithm](http://xades4j.googlecode.com/svn/release/1.3.0/javadoc/reference/xades4j/algorithms/GenericAlgorithm.html) class and pass the algorithm uri.

Then you need to [configure the algorithms provider](https://code.google.com/p/xades4j/wiki/ChangingAlgorithms) on the signing profile that you're using to create signers. You can define a new provider or maybe extend the default and override the needed methods. To register the provider on the signing profile you use the [withAlgorithmsProviderEx method](http://xades4j.googlecode.com/svn/release/1.3.0/javadoc/reference/xades4j/production/XadesSigningProfile.html).

Comment: Thanks. I created, for example the class for c1411 omitcomment this way:      `public class CanonicalXMLWithoutComments11 extends Algorithm{
    public CanonicalXMLWithoutComments11(){
 super(Canonicalizer.ALGO_ID_C14N11_OMIT_COMMENTS);
    }
}`  Do i need also to add the binding to `AlgorithmParametersBindingsModule` class?

Comment: I didn't add the option to register new parameter marshallers on the profiles because I wanted to give a try to the marshallers approach first :) So, yes, you'll need to register it on the module or use the `GenericAlgorithm` class.